# django doesn't see the postgis database on heroku

Tags: django, heroku, postgis, geodjango

I deployed my geodjango website on Heroku, and it works, except:

The website does not show any of the data in the database.

Migrating to Heroku goes well:

```
Running python manage.py migrate on ⬢ countrycompare... up, run.5217 (Free)
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, compare, contenttypes, flatpages, sessions, sites
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying compare.0001_initial... OK
  Applying compare.0002_remove_worldborder_geom... OK
  Applying compare.0003_auto_20180422_1605... OK
  Applying sites.0001_initial... OK
  Applying flatpages.0001_initial... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
  Applying sites.0002_alter_domain_unique... OK
```

And when I look into the postgis database the data is all there:

```
heroku pg:psql
--> Connecting to postgresql-clean-31400
psql (9.6.6, server 10.3 (Ubuntu 10.3-1.pgdg16.04+1))
WARNING: psql major version 9.6, server major version 10.
         Some psql features might not work.
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

countrycompare::DATABASE=> \dt
                      List of relations
 Schema |            Name            | Type  |     Owner
--------+----------------------------+-------+----------------
 public | auth_group                 | table | wfmqwxgtkefsjo
 public | auth_group_permissions     | table | wfmqwxgtkefsjo
 public | auth_permission            | table | wfmqwxgtkefsjo
 public | auth_user                  | table | wfmqwxgtkefsjo
 public | auth_user_groups           | table | wfmqwxgtkefsjo
 public | auth_user_user_permissions | table | wfmqwxgtkefsjo
 public | compare_worldborder        | table | wfmqwxgtkefsjo
 public | django_admin_log           | table | wfmqwxgtkefsjo
 public | django_content_type        | table | wfmqwxgtkefsjo
 public | django_flatpage            | table | wfmqwxgtkefsjo
 public | django_flatpage_sites      | table | wfmqwxgtkefsjo
 public | django_migrations          | table | wfmqwxgtkefsjo
 public | django_session             | table | wfmqwxgtkefsjo
 public | django_site                | table | wfmqwxgtkefsjo
 public | spatial_ref_sys            | table | wfmqwxgtkefsjo
(15 rows)
```

But when I access the website (http://countrycompare.herokuapp.com) all the content that's stored in the database is missing.

How do I solve this?

This is my database connection setup:

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES = { 'default': dj_database_url.config(
    default = 'postgis://wfmqwxgtkefsjo:24da873c123456bfbdfe594ce47e98e8328241aa3eafdf34a989295c207ffc0a@ec2-174-129-41-64.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/denspee4q3d4il'
        )
    }

DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis'
```

I've set

```
heroku config:set BUILD_WITH_GEO_LIBRARIES=1
```

And use cedar-stack 14 (16 won't support the geo libraries yet).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What makes you think there is content in the database? All of those migrations start from initial, implying that this is a new db, and none of them mention inserting items.

Comment: You're right, the data wasn't there! Clearly I case where I ought have retraced my steps a little more thorougly. Put the data in now with a pg_dump. I had understood from online tutorials that the makemigrations bit would take care of everything but I probably misunderstood. Thank you in any case, your comment was a great help!

Comment: Hello, I am interested in knowing how did you deploy this application to Heroku.  Could you please share the details with me?  Thanks.  Bharat

Comment: Hi Bharat, I just followed the tutorial by Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python?singlepage=true which is very comprehensive. Apart from this sticking point with the database.Good luck!

Comment: Thanks MSDMMM.  How did you account for the GDAL and GEOS libraries on Heroku?  On my local machine this is easy, but it points to the environment variables which have dependencies to the local path.

Comment: Hi Bharat, I think I used a buildpack such as this one: https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/daegun/heroku-buildpack-geodjango (it was some ago and I cannot find my notes on this). Be mindful that cedar-stack 16 might not be compatible with geodjango (see above) and include the library paths in your settings, as is described on the buildpack website

Comment: Can we add postgis extension to free postgres db on heroku??